# Disable resizing of fixed flex

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm using this html below to display a flex view on my website. But changing the text **(length of the text)** from a div will lead to the crazy-looking autoresizing.

How can I avoid this resizing in relation to this special **div element below**? How to keep the same layout when the click button is clicked?

Edit: **I would like that neither the size nor the position of any element changes. (No matter how much text is inside!)**

```html
<div style="position: fixed; width:100%; height: 30%; left:0%; top: 0%; background: black; display: flex; justify-content: space-around; text-align: center; color: white">
   <div>
       <div style="font-size: 17px">Info A</div>
       <div style="font-size: 29px;" id="text">text1</div>
   </div>
   <div>
       <div style="font-size: 17px">Info B</div>
       <div style="font-size: 29px;">text2</div>
   </div>
   <div>
       <div style="font-size: 17px">Info C</div>
       <div style="font-size: 29px;">text3</div>
   </div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br>
<input onclick="document.getElementById('text').innerHTML+='.'" type="button" value="click">
```

Comment: You mean how to keep the same layout when the click button is clicked?

Comment: You mean not resize the first `<div>` although its contents will be overloaded with dots?

Comment: I would like that neither the size nor the position changes. no matter how much text is inside

Comment: ok you should really edit the question to specify that so no one else will get confused on what you are asking

Comment: @Huangism I've deleted my first answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
 .wrapper{
    width:100%; 
    background: black; 
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: space-around; 
    text-align: center; 
    color: white;
}

.wrapper > div{
    flex: 1;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
       <div>
           <div style="font-size: 17px">Info A</div>
           <div style="font-size: 29px;" id="text">text1</div>
       </div>
       <div>
           <div style="font-size: 17px">Info B</div>
           <div style="font-size: 29px;">text2</div>
       </div>
       <div>
           <div style="font-size: 17px">Info C</div>
           <div style="font-size: 29px;">text3</div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <br><br><br><br>
    <input onclick="document.getElementById('text').innerHTML+='.'" type="button" value="click">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  if(e.target.id == "button")
   document.getElementById('text').innerHTML+='.';
});
```

```css
#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  flex-basis: 1 1 100%;
}
#navigation > div {
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
#button {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
   <div>
       <div style="font-size: 17px">Info A</div>
       <div style="font-size: 29px;" id="text">text1</div>
   </div>
   <div>
       <div style="font-size: 17px">Info B</div>
       <div style="font-size: 29px;">text2</div>
   </div>
   <div>
       <div style="font-size: 17px">Info C</div>
       <div style="font-size: 29px;">text3</div>
   </div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br>
<button id="button">click</button>
```

Edit: To lock the tekst as well. I would do it with align it left and than adding a padding to it:

```
#navigation > div > div:nth-child(2) {
  padding-left: 10%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `flex: 1 0 33%;` to the elements you don't want to resize. This is equivalent to:

```
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 0;
flex-basis: 33%;
```

```html
<div style="position: fixed; width:100%; height: 30%; left:0%; top: 0%; background: black; display: flex; justify-content: space-around; text-align: center; color: white">
   <div style="flex: 1 0 33%;">
       <div style="font-size: 17px">Info A</div>
       <div style="font-size: 29px;" id="text">text1</div>
   </div>
   <div style="flex: 1 0 33%;">
       <div style="font-size: 17px">Info B</div>
       <div style="font-size: 29px;">text2</div>
   </div>
   <div style="flex: 1 0 33%;">
       <div style="font-size: 17px">Info C</div>
       <div style="font-size: 29px;">text3</div>
   </div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br>
<input onclick="document.getElementById('text').innerHTML+='.'" type="button" value="click">
```

Comment: Need a little more because it still happens, probably need word break

Comment: The second and third cells are still the same size. The first cell is expanding and so is the container. You can set a max-width on the container to help avoid that.

Comment: It looks like the shift still happens. I want none of the elements to move.

Comment: Yes, we can hack this by adding `max-width:33%` to each cell, but that defeats the benefits of using flexbox in the first place.  If you don't want the cells to "flex" their size according to their contents, then I think flexbox is the wrong solution for you.

Comment: @Jonas0000 you need to add `word-break: break-all;`

Answer (score -2):

Here's an example of using `max-width` with your code. The first block will never be wider than `150px` and text which which will overflow will be hidden.

```css
.wrapper{
    width:100%; background: black; display: flex; justify-content: space-around; text-align: center; color: white;
}

.wrapper > div{
    flex: 1;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div style="max-width: 150px">
       <div style="font-size: 17px">Info A</div>
       <div style="font-size: 29px;" id="text">text1</div>
   </div>
   <div>
       <div style="font-size: 17px">Info B</div>
       <div style="font-size: 29px;">text2</div>
   </div>
   <div>
       <div style="font-size: 17px">Info C</div>
       <div style="font-size: 29px;">text3</div>
   </div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br>
<input onclick="document.getElementById('text').innerHTML+='.'" type="button" value="click">
```

Comment: @Jonas0000 it's your choice but rach8garg deserves the checkmark, if you are going with `text-overflow:ellipsis;`